# Undo Overwrite of Python Built-In

Tags: python, function, module, namespaces, built-in

In Python there are several [built-in functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open).  Take open for example `open`.  I can fire up a Python console and get some info about `open` by doing the following:

```
>> open    
>>(built-in function open)
```

But if I were to do something like this:

```
>> # I know it's bad practice to import all items from the namespace    
>> from gzip import *    
>> open    
>>(function open at 0x26E88F0)
```

It appears that, for the rest of my console session, all calls to the `open` function will not use the built-in function but the one in the `gzip` module.  Is there any way to redefine a built-in function in Python back to the original?  It's easy if I have a reference to the desired function, like below:

```
def MyOpen(path):
  print('Trivial example')

open = MyOpen
```

How do you obtain a reference for built-in functions once those references have been overwritten?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can simply delete the global:

```
del open
```

or you can import the [`__builtin__` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/__builtin__.html) (Python 2) or [`builtins` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html) (Python 3) to get to the original:

```
import __builtin__

__builtin__.open
```

Name lookups go first to your global namespace, then to the built-ins namespace; if you delete the global name `open` it'll no longer be in the way and the name lookup progresses to the built-ins namespace, or you can access that namespace directly via the imported module.